# different between uniformly cauchy and uniformly converge

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I am trying to figure out whats the different between "uniformly converge" and "uniformly cauchy" 
I been thinking if its cauchy, then think about in graph that two lines are getting close,, how can it be uniform???

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add the definitions of the two concepts? To me, uniform convergence has to do with sequences of functions, while uniform cauchy convergence is related to general sequences, so I'm not sure I understand what is your question

Comment: yes sure. So i had a definitions of uniformly cauchy is that if j, k > N, then {fj(x)-fk(x)}< eplison for all x in I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the definitions :

Consider a set $X$, a metric space $(E,d)$ and a sequence of maps $f_n:X\to E$.

- The sequence $(f_n)$ is said to be uniformly convergent if there exists a map $g:X\to E$ such that :

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in X}d\left(f_n(x),g(x)\right)=0$$

- The  sequence $(f_n)$ is said to be uniformly Cauchy if :

$$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N\in\mathbb{N};\,\forall p\ge N,\forall q\ge N,\;\sup_{x\in X}d\left(f_p(x),f_q(x)\right)\le\epsilon$$

It can be proved that :

1. without any assumption on $(E,d)$, uniform convergence implies uniform Cauchy criterion.
2. if $(E,d)$ is complete, those two notions are equivalent.

---

**Proof of UCV $\implies$ U-Cauchy**

Given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\ge N$ implies :

$$\forall x\in X,\,d\left(f_n(x),g(x)\right)\le\frac\epsilon2$$

If $p\ge N$ and $q\ge N$ then for all $x\in X$, by triangle inequality :

$$d\left(f_p(x),f_q(x)\right)\le d\left(f_p(x),g(x)\right)+d\left(g(x),f_q(x)\right)\le\frac\epsilon2+\frac\epsilon2=\epsilon$$Hence :

$$\sup_{x\in X}d\left(f_p(x),f_q(x)\right)\le\epsilon$$as desired.$\tag{QED}$

Comment: is that possible that to proof that :"uniform convergence implies uniformly Cauchy  uniform convergence"

Comment: @LuoBobby: Yes. Editing ...